# Post will not load via ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, ajax

I have inherited a WP 3.2.1 site which uses [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) to load content via ajax. This was working before I enabled permalinks on the site. The Custom Post Type UI plugin is installed. I can browse to my custom post type at mysite.com/story/name-of-story but loading via ajax results in a 404.

The links which trigger the $.get code in prettyPhoto look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>&ajax=true&count=<?php echo $count ?>" rel="story[ajax]"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, array(75, 75));?></a>
```

If I change the permalink settings back to 'default'. the post content is loaded into the popup. The hrefs being called via XHR while it is working look like this:

http://mysite.com/?story=name-of-story&ajax=true&count=37

I've tried removing all query parameters from the permalink URLS and this did not resolve the problem. Can anyone shed any light on what might be going on here?

Comment: It sounds like you need to look more into how to use ajax on WordPress sites.  Check this out: http://wpajax.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ajax requests should be routed through the handy `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` file.

It works with the great WP hooks system.  So you send an "action" with your request and use that as part of the action into which you hook your function.

So, let's say your ajax call looks like this (with jQuery)

```
jQuery('a.ajax').click(function(e){
    data = {
        'action': 'wpse31321_action',
        'story': 1 // IDs are easier to deal with...
    }
    jQuery.get(
        'http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data,
        function(resp){
            // do stuff with the response.
        }
    );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then, in your functions.php file or a plugin, you need to hook into `wp_ajax_wpse31321_action` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse31321_action`.  This is the part that does the work: you have access to the complete WP api inside your hooked function.  Get posts, whatever.

`wp_ajax_[some_action]` is for logged in users.  `wp_ajax_nopriv_[some_action]` is for everyone else. `[some_action]` is, of course, the action you send along with your request. `wpse31321_action` in our example.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse31321_action', 'wpse31321_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse31321_action', 'wpse31321_ajax' );
function wpse31321_ajax()
{
    // you have access to $_REQUEST, $_POST and $_GET here...
    if( isset ( $_REQUEST['story'] ) )
    {
        $story = get_post( (int) $_REQUEST['story'] );
        if( ! $story ) die( '-1' );
        echo $story->post_content;
        die(); // Always kill the script after echoing out what you need.   
    }
    else
    {
        die( '-1' );
    }
}
```

You can do whatever you want to manipulate the data before echoing it out.  The above is a really simplistic answer, without much error checking or security built in.  But it should get you started.

Further reading:

http://wpajax.com/

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply. However, What I am really interested in is why the ajax call works with permalinks off and not with them enabled?

Comment: We would have to see more of your code to answer that (what do all of those URL parameter do? Where is that code?).  But I suspect it's because you need to grab the actual permalink with the query string appended to it (eg `http://www.yoursite.com/story/story-slug/?para1=value1&param2=value2`, etc).

Comment: The problem was that the old link already had the '?' in the URL but it wasn't in the permalink after switching on custom permalinks. Thanks!